# Каким образом заменить каждую четную букву в строке на заглавную?

Tags: python, алгоритм

У нас есть строка s = "hello world". Как заменить каждую четную букву на заглавную?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собираете новую строку из символов исходной строки в цикле, выполняя преобразование в верхний регистр для четных символов (`upper`)

```
s = "hello world"
r = ""
for i, c in enumerate(s):
  r += c if i % 2 else c.upper()
print (r)
```

Четность здесь определяется операцией `% 2` (остаток от деления на два).

[Рабочий пример](https://repl.it/EwcI).

Comment: Стоит упомянуть что `r +=` может для каждого символа новую строку создавать—получается квадратичный алгоритм (CPython имеет специальную оптимизацию для этого случая, но нет никакой гарантии). Пример линейного алгоритма: `''.join([a+b for a,b in zip(s[::2], s[1::2].upper())])`

Comment: Кстати, чётные символы имеют нечётные индексы: первый (нечетный) символ имеет нулевой  (четный) индекс.

Comment: По индексам - вы правы, это все программизм головного мозга, считать, что все с нуля нумеруется ))

Comment: Про создание строки на каждой итерации согласен, но не понял почему квадратичный?

Comment: это хороший вопрос (почему `$'r=""\nfor c in s:\n r += c'` может быть  `O(len(s)**2)` в Питоне). Я думаю, стоит его как отдельный SO задать (это достаточно распространённая gotcha)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

чет/неч можно определять с помощью [итератора](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)

```
def upper(s: iter):
    while True:
        yield next(s)  # нечет
        yield next(s).upper()  # чет

''.join(upper(iter('qwerty')))
```

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что с течением времени придётся код под  [pep 479 поправить](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)