# Хотел сделать цикл 'for', чтобы он брал из списка по букве, и делал их заглавными через одну прим.(пЕрЕбОР, ПеРеБоР)

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, for

```py
a = list("перебор")
for i in a:
    i = i.upper()
    print(i)
```

Comment: И что помешало так сделать?

Comment: Я застрял из-за того что не понял как по индексу вытащить элемент.

Comment: Откуда вытащить?  По какому индексу? Вы пробовали найти ответ на свой вопрос в учебнике?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом заменить каждую четную букву в строке на заглавную?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607626/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```py
a = list("перебор")
for i in range(len(a)):
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        a[i] = a[i].upper()
        print(a[i], end='')
    else:
        print(a[i], end='')
print('\n')
```

Проходим счётчиком по номерам элементов с помощью `range()`, если номер чётный (нацело делится на 2), делаем букву заглавной, иначе – нет.

`end = ''` добавлено, чтобы слова выводились в строчку, а не в столбик.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо использовать индексы:

```
a = list("перебор")
to_uppercase = True      # Первую букву сделать прописной

for i in a:
    if to_uppercase:
        i = i.upper()
    print(i, end="")
    to_uppercase = not to_uppercase     # Переключение да <-> нет

print()
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ПеРеБоР
> ```

Comment: Окей, а если мне не нужно делать первую прописной? А оставить заглавной и пропустить, тогда что?

Comment: Тогда измените `to_uppercase = True` на  `to_uppercase = False`.

Comment: Это будет не верно, откуда вы сможете узнать, какое слово будет начинаться с заглавной, а какое нет, если оно к примеру берется из списка

Comment: Я не понял, что вы хотите в отличие от вашего оригинального вопроса. Не было бы лучше задать отдельный вопрос, т.к. в нем более места на объяснение и примеры? (Или же оценить мой ответ, т.к он правильно отвечает на ваш исходный вопрос?)

Comment: Это решение костыль и я не `ТС`, если что =)

Comment: @And, объясните, пожалуйста, я не понимаю — почему костыль? В чем оно хуже чем принятый ответ (ку которому у вас нет претензий)?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a = "перебор"
''.join((odd.upper() + even) for (odd, even) in zip_longest(a[::2], a[1::2], fillvalue=''))  # ПеРеБоР
```